# How do I specify a KEY_FUNCTION for a specific @cache_page

Tags: python, django, caching

I need to update cache for specific view in depends of what time is it. Not just 60mins long live of cached page, but it should become new in concrete time - when the new hour begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something like this:

```
import datetime
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page


def my_cache(time_func, *args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        def wraps(*args, **kwargs):
            @cache_page(time_func())
            def inner_func(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)    
            return inner_func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wraps
    return decorator


def till_hour():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return (60 - now.minute) * 60 + (60 - now.second)


@my_cache(time_func=till_hour)
def my_view(request):
    ... # view code_here
```

So we create a decorator with parameters(`time_func` as first parameter) and wrap our view in a series of wrappers, so that cache_page decorator would be called for every call of the wrapped function. So each time our view is called with a different result from time_func.

This doesn't look like the perfect way to do it since cache_page is actually called many times, so it might be better to investigate the code behind `cache_page` a little more.

Comment: should not it be `return inner_func(...)`?

Comment: Also you can toy with the code, to implement smth inside `wraps` function other than `@cache_page` call. Like getting cache and getting/setting key by hand. =)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As explained by teferi, this won't work as the time is evaluated at server start.

The following code will get the minutes until the next hour, caching it that number of minutes.

```
import datetime
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60-datetime.datetime.now().minute)
def your_view(request):
    pass
```

Comment: tricky enough:) lets wait - may be there are other approaches

Comment: I'm afraid your code is wrong, since it will be evaluated once and datetime.now() will be called once - when the server starts. So if you start server at 30 minutes it will always cache every page for 30 minutes. Also cache_page takes seconds as parameter, not minutes.